# Topical question closed as off topic

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint) about git, Heroku, and ssh has been closed as off topic, but the question asked seems entirely appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Why is it considered off topic?

Comment: Moderators are not perfect. CasperOne used to be trigger happy ;)

Comment: Aaaand... about to get re-opened.

Comment: Question now re-opened... I am sure you are glad you asked on Meta :)

Comment: @Oded Used to be. I beg to differ sometimes. ;)

Comment: @JoshMein - Well... he's a bit less so than he used to be.

Comment: I figured this would be the outcome ;-)

Comment: The community comes to the rescue!